# VS2013 allowing non-standard code?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I was experimenting with the different value categories introduced with C++11, before I tried a line of code which in my mind doesn't make sense, **but compiled anyway with no warnings**:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
int val;
   A() : val(10) {}
   A(const A& other) : val(other.val) {}
   A(A&& other) : val(other.val) {}
};

int main()
{
   A& a = A();
   cout << a.val << endl; // prints '10'
   return 0;
}
```

The line which concerns me:

```
A& a = A();
```

Now, from what I understand (which is probably wrong), `A()` is a prvalue. In my mind, this means it is a temporary which has no lifetime beyond the expression it appears in.

Does this not mean that the reference type `a` should not be able to bind to it?

I've looked around hard and can't find anywhere where this behaviour is stated to be correct, which is understandable as it doesn't make conceptual sense (to me, at least). The reference type `a` is certainly referencing *something*, since I can access `val` as normal.

**So my question is, is this code non-standard and only valid according to VS, or is there something here that I've completely misunderstood (which is likely)?**

Comment: you forgot to show how `val` is declared

Comment: neither clang nor gcc [will have it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb655968d6054b02)

Comment: Could it be that a copy-constructor is called to create A& a? What will happen if the copy-constructor is made private (thus disabling the default copy-constructor too)?

Comment: @MikeBessonov : no, references are created by copying an address. No form of constructor is needed. References are defined in the standard in terms of an *alias*, i.e. a new name for an existing thing. It does not change the total number of `A` objects, so no constructor.

Comment: @sp2danny : yes, you are right, this is what the standard implies. But in this case A& a would be left pointing to an address of the stack which does not contain a valid object anymore.

Comment: _"Also, I couldn't tag prvalue because its not already a tag, sorry."_ None of those tags were useful anyway, so don't apologise for not being able to add another.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sorry for some reason none of the tags I put it originally went through.

Comment: @Fear: Look at the edit history. I removed them. Please stop adding pointless tags that nobody is ever going to search for.

Comment: @FearSenpai: If you turn up the warning level to `/W4` the compiler emits this warning "warning C4239: nonstandard extension used: 'initializing': conversion from 'A' to 'A &'"